# Fix "is not valid in a csv row" for jq, by transforming array to string

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, jq

I try to export a CSV from Neo4j with jq, with:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic myBase64hash=" -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json \
  -d '{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH path=(()<--(p:Person)-->(h:House)<--(s:Street)-->(n:Neighbourhood)) RETURN path"}]}' \
  http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit \
  | jq -r '(.results[0]) | .columns,.data[].row | @csv' > '/tmp/export-subset.csv'
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): array ([{"email":"...) is not valid in a csv row
```

I think it's because of I have multiple e-mail adresses,
is it possible to place all of them in a CSV cell seperated by comma?
How can I achieve that with `jq`?

**Edit:**

This is an example of my JSON file:

```
{"results":[{"columns":["path"],"data":[{"row":[[{"email":"gdggdd@gmail.com"},{},{"date_found":"2011-11-29 12:51:14","last_name":"Doe","provider_id":2649,"first_name":"John"},{},{"number":"133","lon":3.21114,"lat":22.8844},{},{"street_name":"Govstreet"},{},{"hood":"Rotterdam"}]],"meta":[[{"id":71390,"type":"node","deleted":false},{"id":226866,"type":"relationship","deleted":false},{"id":63457,"type":"node","deleted":false},{"id":227100,"type":"relationship","deleted":false},{"id":65076,"type":"node","deleted":false},{"id":214799,"type":"relationship","deleted":false},{"id":63915,"type":"node","deleted":false},{"id":226552,"type":"relationship","deleted":false},{"id":71120,"type":"node","deleted":false}]]}]}],"errors":[]}
```

Comment: could you put an example of `curl --header "Authorization: Basic myBase64hash=" -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json \
  -d '{"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH path=(()<--(p:Person)-->(h:House)<--(s:Street)-->(n:Neighbourhood)) RETURN path"}]}' \
  http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit` so it will be easier to run your example

Comment: 1. @csv requires its input to be an array of atoms.  2. For the given input, what output are you expecting?  3.  Why in your jq filter are you just looking at results[0]?

Comment: @peak 1: I don't think I can change the JSON structure. 2: I expect columns for: email, date_found, first_name, last_name, provider_id, number, lon, lat, street_name and hood. 3: I use `results[0]`, because I want the first entry as I only send one Cypher query. Also see: https://neo4j.com/blog/export-csv-from-neo4j-curl-cypher-jq/

Comment: Use jq to modify the JSON structure, and then pipe the array(s) to @csv.

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me but I'm not familiar with Cypher syntax or how your data is actually structured, you don't provide much detail about that.  But what I can gather, based on your sample output, each "row" item seems to correspond to what you return in your Cypher query.

Apparently you're returning `path` which is an entire set of nodes and relationships, and not necessarily just the data you're actually interested in.

```
MATCH path=(()<--(p:Person)-->(h:House)<--(s:Street)-->(n:Neighbourhood))
RETURN path
```

You just want the email addresses so you should probably just return the email.  If I understand the syntax correctly, you could change that to this:

```
MATCH (i)<--(p:Person)-->(h:House)<--(s:Street)-->(n:Neighbourhood)
RETURN i.email
```

I believe that should result in something that looks something like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [ "email" ],
      "data": [
        {
          "row": [
            "gdggdd@gmail.com"
          ],
          "meta": [
            {
              "id": 71390,
              "type": "string",
              "deleted": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

Then it should be trivial to export that data to csv using jq since the rows can be converted directly:

```
.results[0] | .columns, .data[].row | @csv
```

---

On the other hand, I could be completely wrong on what that output would actually look like.  So just working with your example, if you just want emails, you need to map the rows to just the email.

```
.results[0] | .columns, (.data[].row | map(.[0].email)) | @csv
```

---

In case I misinterpreted, if you were intending to output all values and not just the email, you should select just the values in your Cypher query.

```
MATCH (i)<--(p:Person)-->(h:House)<--(s:Street)-->(n:Neighbourhood)
RETURN i.email, p.date_found, p.last_name, p.provider_id, p.first_name,
    h.number, h.lon, h.lat, s.street_name, n.hood
```

Then if my assumptions on the output are correct, the trivial jq query should give you your csv.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the keys in their original order, use `keys_unsorted`.  This should get you on your way:

```
$ jq -r -c '.results[0] | .data[] | .row[]
  | add
  | keys_unsorted as $keys
  | ($keys, [.[$keys[]]])
  | @csv' input.json
```

(The newlines here are mainly for legibility.)

With your illustrative input, the output would be:

```
"email","date_found","last_name","provider_id","first_name","number","lon","lat","street_name","hood"
"gdggdd@gmail.com","2011-11-29 12:51:14","Doe",2649,"John","133",3.21114,22.8844,"Govstreet","Rotterdam"
```

Of course, in practice, you will probably have multiple lines of data, so in that case, you will probably want to make adjustments to ensure the headers are only printed once.

Comment: The column names and cell values are now not in the right order. The column headers are also repeated, but I didn't get a error this time.

Comment: As I said, this should get you on your way.  This is not a free programming service.